# how to print the vertices of the shortest path returned by the following object of JUNG

Tags: java, jung

DijkstraDistance shortestPath = new DijkstraDistance(network);

Is there any way to display the vertices returned in the shortest path?

Answer (score 2):

```
ShortestPathUtils.getPath()
```

is what you're looking for.